# How to find no of rows with same value in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have one table with event_id & image_id. I want to find the no of rows which with the same value -> max in this table.

means in this table output should like:
1508706279  -> image_id
4  -> no of rows

here is my table.

[image]

below is the code which i have tried.

```
$sql2 = "select image_id, COUNT(*) as count from user_likes where event_id  = '$id' GROUP BY image_id";

                    if($result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {

                        $result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

                        $win = $result1['image_id'];
                        $count = $result1['count'];

                    }
```

Now, i can't understand what is issue but this code works fine when there are rows between id 52 to 60 
it shows output:

1508706279  -> image_id
4  -> no of rows

but when i add two more rows with id 64 & 65 
it shows output:

818525590  -> image_id
1  -> no of rows

help me in this what mistake i am doing here.!!

Comment: its because `65` has different `image_id` name and you are grouping with `image_id`

Comment: So, what can i do here to get proper output?

Comment: if you want to get number of rows which has same values based on `event_id` then remove  `GROUP BY image_id`

Comment: Thank u. will check it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query return a  collection of image_id and count.
The collection is not ordered  so you have the first one from select 
if you need  the max try ordering by count(*) desc

```
  $sql2 = "select image_id, COUNT(*) as count 
            from user_likes 
            where event_id  = '$id' 
            GROUP BY image_id
            ORDER BY count(*) DESC";
```

and you can limit to 1 if you need one row only

```
  $sql2 = "select image_id, COUNT(*) as count 
            from user_likes 
            where event_id  = '$id' 
            GROUP BY image_id
            ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: oopss.!! Silly mistake. Works perfectly. thank u so much :) will accept your ans.